# Lose effect JQuery in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't know why when I use Ajax to paging and search in MVC4, but when I search or click to next page. I see my page is lost all effects Jquery.

This is my javascript code:

```
$(function () {
$(".listview > li").hover(function () {
    $(this).children(".badge.right").css({ "display": "block", "animation": "myanomation 0.5s" });
},
function () {
    $(this).children(".badge.right").css({ "display": "none" });
});

var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {
    var $form = $(this);
    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-ms-target"));
        $target.replaceWith(data);
    });

    return false;
};

//var submitAutoCompleteForm = function (event, ui) {
//    var $input = $(this);
//    $input.val(ui.item.name);

//    var $form = $input.parents("form:first");
//    $form.submit();

//    return false;
//};

var createAutocomplete = function () {
    var $input = $(this);

    var options = {
        minLength: 1,
        source: $input.attr("data-ms-autocomplete")
    }

    $input.autocomplete(options)
          .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
              return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.ui-autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a href='/Product/Details/" + item.id + "'><div class='icon'><img src='/Uploads/Images/Products/" + item.icon + "' /></div><div class='data'><h4>" + item.name + "</h4><div class='static-rating small' data-role='rating' data-param-vote='off' data-param-rating='" + item.rating + "'><div class='rating-value' style='width: " + (item.rating / 5) * 100 + "%;'></div></div></div><p>$ " + item.price + "</p></div></a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
          };

    return false;
};

var getPage = function () {
    $a = $(this);

    var options = {
        url: $a.attr("href"),
        type: "get"
    }

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var target = $a.parents("div.pagedList").attr("data-ms-target");
        $(target).replaceWith(data);
    });

    return false;
};

$("form[data-ms-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);
$("input[data-ms-autocomplete]").each(createAutocomplete);
$(".main-content").on("click", ".pagedList a[href]", getPage);
});
```

I hope people can help me. Thank you!

Comment: _"my page is lost all effects Jquery"_ - please explain the problem and the steps to reproduce it somewhat better. A trimmed-down version of your page (HTML + JS) could help us (and you!) to determine the location of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax submit is replacing all the elements in a div, if certain jQuery "effects" require binding to the element then they will have no knowledge of the newly added DOM elements.  If this is the case then your jQuery "effects" will need to be added to the new elements.